# Package parsing error on app installation on Android N

Tags: java, android

My app is not presented in Play Market, so I've implemented auto update feature inside of it. Basically it does this:

1. on app start ask backend if there is new version;
2. if new version available, queue APK download using system DownloadService (after getting WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission);
3. after download is finished, start app installation with this code snippet:

   ```
   Intent i = new Intent();
   i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(fileUri.getPath())), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
   i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   context.startActivity(i);
   ```

Everything goes well on devices with SDK level 22 or less, but when I'm trying to update app on Android 6, I get message "Parse Error : There is a problem parsing the package."
Here is the snippet from my build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.id"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 22
        versionName "1.3.3"
        generatedDensities = []
    }
    aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
}
```

When I'm downloading the same APK using browser and starting installation using file manager, installation goes well.
Has anyone ideas on how to fix this problem?

Comment: http://www.technicalnotes.org/fix-parse-error-in-android-there-is-a-problem-parsing-the-package/

Comment: @Tez that solutions don't work. If it was one of them, the problem would be present on devices with all API levels, but it is specific to Android 6.

Comment: @FyodorSherstobitov; Have you fixed this issue, still with File Provider am facing this.